# Define variables per folder in dbt

Tags: sql, dbt

I'm trying to have a structure to run a dbt project, where I have multiple entities (bank, names, cars). I'm going to have exactly the same code for them all.

Based on that, I'm trying to have several folder with the same code, where I can define inside the `dbt_project.yaml`file. The idea is something like this:

```
vars:
  db_name: 'db_official'

  staging:
    bank: 'variable_bank'
    car: 'variable_car'
    name: 'variable_name'
```

The variable "db_name" works. So, my the two problems I'm having are:

1. How to have this structure inside the the yaml file?
2. How to reference this structure inside each file?
3. (extra) Any other ideas how to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vars` are basically globals. They can be scoped to your whole project, or to a package within your project, but not more specifically than that (they share a flat namespace). [See the docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/project-variables).

I would pull out the common code into a macro, then call that macro from each model file, passing in the unique values as string literals in the model file:

```
-- models/staging/bank.sql
{{ my_model_template('variable_bank') }}
```

```
-- models/staging/car.sql
{{ my_model_template('variable_car') }}
```